# Как собрать проект?

Tags: javascript, webpack

[image: Структура проекта]

Имеется данная структура проекта.
Я использовал там express для создания сервера, sass для стилей,также имеются шрифты, дополнительно несколько файлов js в разных папках.
Вопрос.
Как собрать весь проект в папку build, чтобы я на выходе получил на выходе всё то, что имеется на картинке 2?

[image: что надо получить]